# App Crashing using popViewControllerAnimated:YES

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to create a back button to return to the main menu of my app, what is happening now, is, once I press the back button, it shows the main menu, but then the app crashes out a second later.

The code I use for back button is;

```
- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

From the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    navigationController = [[myNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I cannot see where I am going wrong? It seems to call the right screen, yet crashes straight after?

EDIT - Here is MenuViewController.m file;

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "MagicAppDelegate.h"
#import "MagicViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];


    [super viewDidLoad];

  //  [self initLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

-(IBAction)onStart:(id)sender
{
    MagicViewController* viewController;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        viewController = [[MagicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MagicViewController_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    else
        viewController = [[MagicViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MagicViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you add some info about the crash? Exception name, stack trace, etc.

Comment: It does not show in the output log for some reason.
It says 
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0)

Comment: Seems you are accessing deallocated memory somewhere. Some likely scenarios are: You have some sort of repeating method/timer that continues after the view controller is popped, causing a message to be sent to the deallocated instance, or some code is trying to access or do something with your view controller after it is popped.

Comment: You should set an 'Exception Breakpoint' which will pause execution right before the Exception is thrown - should help figure out which line is causing the bad access

Comment: Where would I look to see the deallocated memory? Would it be anything that is deallocated when going to that particular view at the beginning?

Comment: I tried the Exception Breakpoint but it does not pause it, it just shows the same errors as before.

Comment: The fact that is crashes after it returns to the previous controller probably means that something you're doing there is the problem, not the code you posted. You should show the code for whatever controller (MenuViewController I presume) you go back to with the pop.

Comment: @rdelmar yes absolutely right. `user1695971` without posting the code of creation of previous controller would not possible to help you..

Comment: I have posted code of previous controller now. @rdelmar

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see anything wrong. In your backButtonPressed method, add a log of self.navigationController.viewControllers and see what that returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code,do u want go mainmenuview controller.

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't understand your code: In the statement `navigationController = [[myNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];` you are sending an `alloc` to something that seems to be the **instance** of class `UINavigationController`, but alloc is a **class** method. I therefore assume myNavigationViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController (but then is should start with a capital letter).
The new instance returned is then assigned directly, i.e. without using a setter method, to variable `navigationController`. It is therefore **not** retained. If your statement returns an autorelease object, it will thus be released as soon as the program returns to the main event loop.
Try thus to use thus a setter method, i.e. `self.navigationController = [[myNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way he's doing this. navigationController retains viewController, and the window, through its rootViewController property, retains navigationController.